# Can we specify the ordering of records to be fetched by Debezium Postgres Kafka connect

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am using debezium Postgres connector to publish messages on Kafka. 
Messages in Postgres are not in ordered as per primary key. But I want to publish messages as per the primary key order.

Whenever I need to recreate Kafka to publish messages from starting, 
I am manually executing clustering command on Postgres table to arrange the rows in order.

But I want to avoid this manual step. 
Is there any way to configure it in Debezium?

Comment: Then SELECT them using an `ORDER BY`

Comment: I am not using any database query to get the data. Debezium automatically detects the changes which is being made in table based on an offset which is stored in a Kafka topic. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Hi, I may misundertand a little bit but are we talking abut reprociessing of messages from scratch? If yes then there is (should be) a snapshotting phase executed when new connector is registered and in this case you can pass your custom select and order data according to your needs.
For ordering in Kafka topic itself the Kafka Streams might help - but then you have a problem as you must know when the strem ends.

Comment: @JiriPechanec Thanks for your comment. Yes, its regarding re-processing of messages. Could you please share some reference to implement the snapshotting?

Comment: @JiriPechanec Thanks for the direction. It did the trick. By using SNAPSHOT_SELECT_STATEMENT_OVERRIDES_BY_TABLE configuration property, it can be achieved.